# Why date changes when i pass from php array into json?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, inertiajs

I have this data in my Controller in Laravel 9;

```
public function index()
{
    $activites = \App\Models\Activity::all(['title', 'body', 'created_at']);

    return Inertia::render('Admin/Activites/Index', ['activites' => $activites]);
}
```

But when I print the data in the browser, I get `created_at:"2023-03-06 08:34:36` instead of `created_at:"2023-03-06 09:34:36`

Does json decoder change dates?

Comment: If I am not confused, it is "changing" the date to the local time, but I honestly am not sure... someone that knows JS should help you more

Comment: Is your timezone 1 hour off from UTC? Because if I was writing a library to produce date/time strings without a timezone included, the only sane option would be to convert them to UTC.

Comment: What timezone is using your database or especially your database table column? What default timezone is using php at runtime? These are two different things you have to deal with.